# Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, opencv

I'm using the matchFeature example from NodeJS but when i try to test the following error occurs in the
 const cv = require('opencv4nodejs'); line from the example.

> test/matchFeature.test.js
>
> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at Function.keys ()
>
> at Object. (node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js:63:8)
>   at Object.
>   (node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/opencv4nodejs.js:11:79)

I think is a problem when loading the module, but i cant fix it.
I'm using Jest for testing.

If i run the file with NodeJS, works without problems:

https://prnt.sc/sq41s9

And if i run test with jest, gives the error above:

https://prnt.sc/sq42mb

The images are from the file cv.js running the file and the test

EDIT: Screenshot from jest index.js (Module null)

https://prnt.sc/sq5rxl

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with a global setup script which loads the module.

```
// setup.js
module.exports = async () => {
    const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');
    console.log('cv.version', cv.version);
};
```

And in the jest Config in package.json:

```
"jest": {
        ...
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "globalSetup": "./setup.js"
    }
```